# Cheapest way of traveling from FCO to Rome by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, layovers, rome, fco

What is the cheapest way of getting to Rome city centre from Leonardo da Vinci airport and how long would it take?

I read about a train and an old line, but I am not sure how that works.

Comment: Did you try reading the [WikiVoyage "Get In" page for the airport](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci-Fiumicino_Airport#Ground_transportation)? That seems to cover most things you'd want to know

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci-Fiumicino_Airport#Ground_transportation), the cheapest transport option is to use [Terravision buses](http://www.terravision.eu/airport_transfer/bus-fiumicino-airport-rome/prices-and-timetable-fiumicino-airport-rome/). The price is 5,80`EUR` one-way or 9`EUR` return. The trip takes 55 minutes.

[image: Screenshot of the Terravision prices taken August 2019]

There are also options available by public bus, but they cost the same if you need to get to the center of Rome.

Answer (score 3):

Cheapest there are the **buses** by [*Terravision*](https://www.terravision.eu/airport_transfer/bus-fiumicino-airport-rome/) and a couple of other bus companies. If you book in advance you can get a one-way for as cheap as **5,80€**. It takes **55 minutes**. Note that here you are not flexible with your departure time. Buying tickets at the booth is possible but at higher prices and may sell out, especially in summer. In the latter case, don't expect any service, just take the train:

---

The most **convenient train** is the [*Leonardo Express*](https://www.trenitalia.com/en/services/fiumicino_airport.html) train which takes you direct to *Roma Termini* station, departing every 15 minutes (30 minutes sometimes) and taking **32 minutes**. The cost is **14€** and a commission may be charged if you buy it at the booth. You have to convalidate it before entering the platform. This train is supposed to run even in case of railway strikes.

---

There is also cheaper [**regional trains**](https://www.trenitalia.com) to *Roma Tiburtina* station for **8€**, every 30 minutes and taking **48 minutes**. Both Termini and Tiburtina are connected to the metro network of Rome. You have to convalidate your ticket.